# Angular: @Injectable service constructed after a component that depends on it

Tags: angular

As the title suggests, I have declared a service that is @Injectable. A component requests that service in its dependencies. However, as the component is constructed, only "undefined" is provided instead of the service instance.
Using console.log shows that the component's constructor is run before that of the service.

See the following stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/injectable-issue

Landmarks:

- The injectable service is ./app/commons/users/services/users.services
- It is part of a module's forRoot call ./app/commons/users/users.module
- The class that expects this dependency is in ./app/store/reducers/users.reducer
- a `debugger;` statement has been set so that dev tools will halt in a place were one can inspect `_usersService` and see it undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why dont you import your userService normally? `import {UserService} from "..."`

Comment: Just to stick with the barrel file, but I now updated the stackblitz with a direct import of the service. Doesn't help though :/

Comment: remove the `canActivate` but from the users route

Comment: won't help as the users route points to ./app/feature/(...) which is lazy loaded while the UsersService is in the ./app/commons and is loaded as forRoot in the app.module

Comment: actually, it does help, i tested it in the stackblitz you sent

Comment: strange, I disabled that line in the app-routing.module file but doesn't help. Just updated the sandbox, you still see the _usersService set in the constructor of the UserStore class?

Comment: I added `import {UsersStore} from './store/reducers/users.reducer';` and provided `UsersStore` in `app.module`. It triggered `debugger` twice, once with undefined and once with an instance of the service you want. I guess there is something like `usersStore = new UsersStore(null)` somewhere. Search through your codebase

Comment: Ahh right, I neglected adding it to the providers. Good job!